# Using exchangelib GetUserAvailability service

Tags: exchangelib

I have a user Contact in Exchange that I need to query the free/busy time info for. I can do that in Outlook by adding them to a calendar invite and then checking the user's free time. Is the same possible with exchangelib?

Answer (score 0):

The `get_free_busy_info` method should do what you want:

```py
import datetime
from exchangelib import Account

a = Account(...)
start = datetime.datetime.now(a.default_timezone)
end = start + datetime.timedelta(hours=6)
accounts = [(a, 'Organizer', False)]
for busy_info in a.protocol.get_free_busy_info(
        accounts=accounts, start=start, end=end
):
    print(busy_info)
```

See https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/#non-account-services

Comment: Didn't realize the first parameter of the tuple could be a string and not an account